# Proof: The inverse of the translation $T_{AB}$ is the translation $T_{BA}$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

> Prove: The inverse of the translation $T_{AB}$ is the translation
>   $T_{BA}$

This is my work so far:

Let P be any point of the plane and set:

$P'=T_{AB} (P)$

We want to show $(T_{AB})^{-1}(P)$=$T_{BA} (P')$

The translation $P'=T_{AB} (P)$ creates a parallelogram $ABP'P$

For some reason, I can't see the link. I drew the parallelogram out and I see the result but I'm not sure how I can go from using and starting out with $T_{AB} (P)$ to all the way to the inverse.

If anyone can help with this proof, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You are trying to show that $(T_{AB})^{-1} = T_{BA}$, so for any $P$ you need $(T_{AB})^{-1}(P) = T_{BA}(P)$.

Comment: Oh okay, but how would I be able to go from $T_{AB}$ to $(T_{AB})^{-1}$ or should I assume $(T_{AB})^{-1}$ first.

Comment: The inverse of a function is the unique function which "reverses" the map, so $(T_{AB})^{-1}$ is the function such that for every $P$, $(T_{AB})^{-1} (T_{AB}(P)) = P$. You should be able to use that property to get what you want.